# Angular-js code minifying Error: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: angularjs, operator-keyword, minify

I am trying to minify my angular-js code using js-minify tool but its throwing an exception as Error: Unexpected token: operator (>)

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: I have an angularjs file app.js. I want to minify the file and load in server. So i used a tool javascript minifier and pasted the code there but its throwing error Error: Unexpected token: operator (>) in this line  "var equityTotal = scope.chartData.length != 0 ? scope.chartData[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) : 0;" but there is no error in the code asap

Comment: The arrow function expression is a new feature introduced in ECMAScript 2015. Does the minifier have support for it?

Comment: Ya i found the problem. I reframed the function removing the arrow function and it worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

The arrow function expression is a new feature introduced in ECMAScript 2015. Your minifier probably does not support it yet. You mentioned that you were trying to do this:

```
scope.chartData[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

You can rewrite it without the arrow function like this:

```
scope.chartData[0].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
}, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a transpiler like https://babeljs.io/ to compile your es6 code down to es5 and than minify/uglify your source code.

In this way you can continue to enjoy writing code in es6.

Comment: Just put your code in here https://babeljs.io/repl/ and it will converted to the desired format.